# OpenGL view and matrixes

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm struggeling to understand how the rendering works in OpenGL.
In my render function, I want something like this...

```
void Window::render() {
//Render scene
//set screen center to be 0,0 (like opengl is by default)
myObject.render();

//Render interface
//set point 0,0 to topleft corner so that I can render this based om screensize
myInterface.render();
```

EDIT: My question is, how do I do it? I've tried fiddeling around with:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

Comment: You really shouldn't use the old fixed-function pipeline function. Though what you would do is simply, change the projection matrix from a perspective matrix (3D) to a orthogonal matrix ("2D").

Comment: Ah, I see. So are there a new way to do this now then?

Comment: The modern way would be to calculate all the matrices yourself and pass them to a shader.

Comment: If you want to avoid having to calculate all the matricies yourself, this library should help: http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.4/index.html